# How to check day cycle or night cycle based on time?

Tags: android

Hi I have a list of times but i want to check whether the time is day cycle or night cycle based on the list of times.

1. Example Night Cycle limit 00:00 to 12:00
2. Example Day Cycle limit 12:00 to 00:00

try{

```
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date date_from = formatter.parse("00:00");
            Date date_to = formatter.parse("12:00");
            Date dateNow = formatter.parse("07:30");
            if (date_from.before(dateNow)) {
                check = "nightCycle";
            } else if (dateNow.before(date_to)) {
                check = "nightCycle";
            } else if (dateNow.after(date_from)) {
                check = "nightCycle";
            } else {
                check = "DayCycle";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: And what's the problem? The code snippet concludes it is "DayCycle" as it should.

Comment: @Henry please check now i updated timings

Comment: @Henry 7:30 should be day cycle but it is showing night cycle

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different conditions depending on the interval crossing midnight or not. Draw a little diagram, this helps to get the conditions right.

```
if (date_from.before(date_to)) { // they are on the same day
    if (dateNow.after(date_from) && dateNow.before(date_to)) {
        check = "nightCycle";
    } else {
        check = "dayCycle";
    }
 } else { // interval crossing midnight
    if (dateNow.before(date_to) || dateNow.after(date_from)) {
        check = "nightCycle";
    } else {
        check = "dayCycle";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working but 05:45 to 06:00 should be night cycle but it is coming under daycycle

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If the night interval is 5:45 to 6:00 then 7:30 is day.

Comment: If the night Cycle limit is 00:00 to 06:00 then 6:00 should be night cycle after 6 should be day cycle

Comment: with this code 5:59 is night, 6:00 is already day. It depends to which interval you want to assign the values exactly on the borders. If you want to have 6:00 still as night it's not difficult to change the code accordingly (left as an exercise).

Comment: Hint: `<=` can be expressed as not `>`.

Comment: `from=00:00`, `to=12:00`, `now=12:01` works for me, it shows day.

Comment: ok please leave that.. Can you please tell that for this condition If the night Cycle limit is 00:00 to 06:00 then 6:00 should be night cycle after 6 should be day cycle

Comment: This is really not difficult and you should be able to solve it on your own. You profit much less, if I just give away the answer.

Comment: if (dateNow.before(date_to) || dateNow.after(date_from) || dateNow.equals(date_to)) {
}

this one is correct??

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any one wants a complete working code modified henry and Shanmugapriyan's solutions a little bit.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date_from = formatter.parse("00:00");
Date date_to = formatter.parse("08:00");
Date dateNow = formatter.parse(formatter.format(new Date()));

System.out.println("date_to: " + date_from);
System.out.println("date_to: " + date_to);
System.out.println("dateNow: " + dateNow);

String check = "dayCycle";
if (date_from.before(date_to)) { // they are on the same day
    if (dateNow.after(date_from) && dateNow.before(date_to)) {
        check = "nightCycle";
    } else {
        check = "dayCycle";
    }
} else { // interval crossing midnight
    if (dateNow.before(date_to) || dateNow.after(date_from)) {
        check = "nightCycle";
    } else {
        check = "dayCycle";
    }
}
System.out.println("Cycle is " + check);
```